# Sending email and password data from frontend to server. Changes to undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, redux

Having some trouble sending data from my frontend to my server. I put in multiple console.log()'s to make reading the error messages and following the data easier.

Basically, the proper information is put into the axios.get call, and sent to the server. However, the server is receiving the information as 'undefined'. This can be seen in the console outputs/errors.

I am wondering if this is due to my frontend being normal javascript, and my server being in typescript?

Here is my full login component (React/Redux):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormField from '../utils/Form/formfield';
import { update, generateData, isFormValid } from '../utils/Form/formActions';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';   
import { loginUser } from '../../actions/user_actions';
import { connect} from 'react-redux';


class Login extends Component {
    state={
        formError: false,
        formSuccuss: '',
        formdata:{
            email: {
                element: 'input',
                value: '',
                config: {
                    name: 'email_input',
                    type: 'email',
                    placeholders: 'Enter your email'
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                valdationMessage:''
            },
            password: {
                element: 'input',
                value: '',
                config: {
                    name: 'password_input',
                    type: 'password',
                    placeholders: 'Enter your password'
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true,
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                valdationMessage:''
            }
        } 
    }

    updateForm = (element) => {
        const newFormdata = update(element,this.state.formdata,'login');
        this.setState({
            formError: false,
            formdata: newFormdata
        })
    }

    submitForm= (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log('submitting form!!!!!');

        let dataToSubmit = generateData(this.state.formdata,'login');
        let formIsValid = isFormValid(this.state.formdata,'login');
        console.log(dataToSubmit);

        if(formIsValid ){
            console.log("form is valid guy!")
            console.log(dataToSubmit);
            this.props.dispatch(loginUser(dataToSubmit)).then(response =>{
                if(response.payload.loginSuccess){
                    console.log(response.payload);
                    this.props.history.push('/user/dashboard');
                }else{
                    this.setState({
                        formError: true
                    })
            }
            });
         } else {
             this.setState({
                 formError: true
             })
        }
    }   

render() {
    return (
        <div className="signin_wrapper">
            <form onSubmit={(event)=> this.submitForm(event)}>

                <FormField
                    id={'email'}
                    formdata={this.state.formdata.email}
                    change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                />

                <FormField
                    id={'password'}
                    formdata={this.state.formdata.password}
                    change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                />

                { this.state.formError ?
                    <div className="error_label">
                        Please check your data
                    </div>
                :null}
                <button onClick={(event)=> this.submitForm(event)}>
                    Log in
                </button>
                <button 
                    style={{marginLeft:'10px'}}
                    onClick={()=> this.props.history.push('/reset_user') }>
                   Forgot my password
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default connect()(withRouter(Login));
```

Here is the Redux action using redux-promise:

```
export function loginUser(dataToSubmit){

   console.log("Inside the action");
   console.log(dataToSubmit);
   console.log("outside the action");

   const request = axios.get(`http://localhost:3333/users/login`,dataToSubmit)
            .then(response => response.data);
   return {
      type: LOGIN_USER,
      payload: request
    }
}
```

This is the login's output. All data seems fine:

```
login.jsx:64 submitting form!!!!!
login.jsx:68 {email: "anemail@gmail.com", password: "passwords"
login.jsx:71 form is valid guy!
login.jsx:72 {email: "anemail@gmail.com", password: "passwords1"}
user_actions.js:87 Inside the action
user_actions.js:88 {email: "anemail@gmail.com", password: "passwords1"}
user_actions.js:89 outside the action
```

Server's index.ts using express and Typescript:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'; import { userRouter } from './routers/user-router';


const app=express();
const port=3333; app.set('port', port);

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '16mb'}))

app.use((req, resp, next) => {

resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", http://localhost:3000); resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); 
resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); 
resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"); next(); });

app.use('/users', userRouter);

const server = app.listen(port, () => { 

console.log(App is running at http://localhost:${port}); });
```

This is the router that receives the data, which is also in typescript:

```
userRouter.get("/login", async (req:Request, resp: Response) => {
  try {

    console.log("Attempting to login user");
    console.log(req.body.email);
    console.log(req.body.password);

    const user = await userDao.getUser(
      req.body.email,
      req.body.password
    );

    console.log("Got User");
    console.log(user);
    resp.json(user);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    resp.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

As you can see here, the data the server receives from the frontend is instantly rendered as 'undefined' even though the frontend displayed the proper information:

```
Attempting to login user
undefined
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'account_id' of undefined
    at Object.userConverter (C:\GitFolder\project2\server\util\converters\userConverter.ts:6:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\GitFolder\project2\server\dao\user-dao.ts:75:29)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\GitFolder\project2\server\dao\user-dao.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Got User
undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I can add more code if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot attach a body to a GET request.

You might want to change your request within the Frontend to POST and read the request as POST on your Backend, then I am sure your body will be available for reading.

GET requests usually have parameters sent within the path itself such as:

```
http://your.backend.com/score/:userId/:levelId
```

POST requests on the other end can have a body attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should return within the then function of promise.

```
export function loginUser(dataToSubmit){

  console.log("Inside the action");
  console.log(dataToSubmit);
  console.log("outside the action");

  axios.post(`http://localhost:3333/users/login`, dataToSubmit).then(response => {
    return {
      type: LOGIN_USER,
      payload: response.data
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Or you can use await like this

```
const myFunc=async (dataToSubmit)=>{

    console.log("Inside the action");
    console.log(dataToSubmit);
    console.log("outside the action");

    const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3333/users/login`,dataToSubmit)
    return {
       type: LOGIN_USER,
       payload: response.data
     }
 }
```

post is used for login as we don't send the body in a get request. check the code below.